# for line in open(..) hangs unexpectedly mid file

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, file-io

When reading a file in the most basic manner like this:

```
with open('/tmp/abs/path/file.txt', 'rb') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print('New line...'
        # calculations
        print('Last line of line-loop')
    print('Ended up outside') # <-- Never reaches this either, which is "fine".
```

The fileoperation hangs mid file with the last output being "Last line of line-loop" meaning the operation hangs on `for line in fh` for some reason.

The file-size is 5025728020 bytes
The file-position: 26957152 bytes

So i thought i'd use epoll() instead to Watch for blocking read by doing:

```
with open('/tmp/abs/path/file.txt', 'rb') as fh:
    watcher = select.epoll()
    watcher.register(fh.fileno(), select.EPOLLIN)
```

This fails however with `operation not permitted`, this has worked so many times in the past for some unknown reason both on files, sockets and stdout pipes, but not on this machine? Or have I just stuck lucky on some special disk-file Before?

Debian, v7.5
Python, v3.3.5

What puzzles me is that i have Three files, one being 1 billion bytes bigger, Another being just mere 3296 bytes. The bigger and the smaller file works perfectly with the same code, the one mentioned does not.

This puzzles me in so many ways that i don't even know where to begin.

Did a `python3.3 -m trace --trace script.py` and it says:

```
script.py(112):                for line in fh:
script.py(113):                    print(fh.tell())
124124124
script.py(112):                for line in fh:
```

And there it hangs.. forever..

Edit: It always hangs on the same place and tail can't get past this point either.
Running: `tail -c+26956052 /file | head`
Gives me one line, and one line only. It should give me more.
Running just a `tail /file` hangs as well..

Tried `file /file` and it gave me:
`... ASCII text, with very long lines`

Martijn got me thinking, and suddenly i remember that "dd" is a thing *sigh*.
Doing `dd if=file ibs=1 skip=26957150 count=100` gives me:

```
;
100+0 records in
0+1 records out
100 bytes (100 B) copied, 5.5e-05 s, 1.8MB/s
```

Something is definetly wrong with this file/hardware.

`strace cat /file > /dev/null` gives:

```
read(3, " some data that is correc"..., 32768) = 32768
write(3, " some data that is correc"..., 32768) = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 32768) = 32768
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 1556) = 1556
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...", 1556) = 1556
read(3, "", 32768)                = 0
close(3)                          = 0
close(1)                          = 0
close(2)                          = 0
exit_group(0)                     = ?
```

All help is apriciated, and i'll investigate the file transfer of this file.
The file is transfered via a scheduled 10min window via scp betweeen a LAN of 64MB/s transferrates. Something might be going wrong here, perhaps rsync will do a better job.

Comment: Sounds like an OS-level issue to me. Can you `cat` the file to `/dev/null` at all? In the shell do `cat /tmp/abs/path/file.txt > /dev/null` and see if that completes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, it appears to be a OS-level issue because tail can't get past this point either. Running just tail hangs completely, and a tail starting on bytes just before the issue gives me the last line before the issue (one single line, then it hangs).

Comment: @MartijnPieters can i cat between two bytes positions in a neat way? That would give me a idea if the next data/lines is missing \n entirely and that's why tail and for line hangs..

Comment: You might want to try `strace cat file >/dev/null`...

Comment: @Torxed: this is not an issue with the contents of the file. This is an issue at the OS or hardware level. I suspect a bad sector.

Comment: @glglgl see the strace, doesn't tell me much except that the data is broken?

Comment: `read(3, " some data that is correc"..., 32768) = 32768
write(3, " some data that is correc"..., 32768) = 32768` doesn't look normal. Don't see why `cat` would write back to the same fd. rsync isn't going to offer better integrity than scp. scp is far better than ftp. But as the others have said, this isn't a problem with the data itself but the storage of the data with the filesystem / on the storage medium.

Comment: @MattH Well to me rsync makes more sense, and a proof of concept that i ran 10 minutes ago showed promesing results. rsync not only compresses the data over a SSH connection (not ftp) but it also validates integrity and file lists prior to sending. And i rsynced the file that scp failed to transfer and it works perfectly at the moment. But then again the scp might be a freak accident and rsync might be vounrable to the same thing. They both use the same subroutine of ssh for sending IIRC?

Comment: You open the file in binary mode ('rb'). You should open it in the text mode ('r' or nothing) when looping through the lines. Or do you want to get the series of lines as `bytes`? Isn't one of the `bytes` line too long?

Comment: @pepr mainly because there's different encodings in the file and `.read()` will fail horribly because of encoding issues. reading it as bytes i have the option to define encoding based on each row instead of the entire file. Also it appears to be quicker to access data in binary form, so i've just stuck with it from that initial research (i might be wrong that's why i'm stating that it was a initial research). :)

Comment: Anyone interested in the 10 points can just write an answer stating that this was a hardware issue causing unreported issues. Re-transfering the file appears to be working and rsync --checksum apperas to be validating the issues when the occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync has some advantages, automatic checksums provide additional protection (over just scp) against in-memory corruption, but as far as I know doesn't re-validate the destination file after writing.

If there was corruption during file transfer checksums would fail and you still should be able to read junk.

The fact that the read fails suggests filesystem or media corruption.